# Is there a way to get a IWin32Window for LINQPad application?

Tags: linqpad

I'm trying to call ShowDialog for a WinForm (actual code to create form is located in the .linq script) and all works ok, but the dialog does not show centered in LINQPad application.  This is problematic when multiple monitors are in play and I'm staring at LINQPad, run my script and dialog pops up on different monitor.  I'm assuming passing in a IWin32Window to ShowDialog will show the dialog centered on the owner, but I don't know how to get the IWin32Window from LINQPad...is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty you'll face in trying to parent the form is that your query runs in a different process to LINQPad.exe.

You can use `LINQPad.Util.HostProcessID` to obtain LINQPad's process ID and then `Process.GetProcessById (Util.HostProcessID).MainWindowHandle` to get the Windows handle, but then you still won't be able to parent your form. The best you can do is call a Win32 function such as `GetWindowRect` to obtain LINQPad's main window position and then manually center your form.

Rather than mess around with this, have you considered just dumping the desired control? LINQPad will then render it in the output pane and start a message loop. For instance:

```
var panel = new Panel { Padding = new Padding(10) };
panel.Controls.Add (new TextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Top });
panel.Controls.Add (new Label { Dock = DockStyle.Top, AutoSize=true, Text="Testing" });
panel.Dump();
```

Note that any forms that you then show from within event handlers on your controls *will* be centered to the parent:

```
panel.Controls[1].Click += (sender, args) =>
    new Form { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent }.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Good to know.  Not the exact behavior I'm looking for though.  Guess I'll either look into GetWindowRect or just accept the form popping up in (seemingly) random monitors :).  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As a small contribution to @Albahari's answer:

```
var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
var handle = Process.GetProcessById(Util.HostProcessID).MainWindowHandle;
var win32Window = new NativeWindow();
win32Window.AssignHandle(handle);
if (dialog.ShowDialog(win32Window) != DialogResult.OK)
{
    "Aborted".Dump();
    return;
}
```